# How to manipulate string to delete quotes?

Tags: php, html, string, forms

I am trying to manipulate a string so that any quotes (") within `<a href>` and `<\a>` get taken out...  Sorry if its been asked before but I just can't get it to work!  By the way, I am POSTing the data from a form and then manipulating the string.  This is basically html but its in the form of a string, and I want to take out quotes on things like images and links...  Another thing is, I do not want to escape the quotes because that would break the link...  And the whole point is that the html can be used and work fine...  But now, something is automatically creating a second set of quotes inside the normal quotes, like this: `<a href="\"http://www.example.com/\""></a>`

**Example input would be:** `<p><a href="http://www.example.com">example</a></p>`

**Heres how it appears when I echo it however:** `<p><a href=\"http://www.example.com\">example</a></p>`

**Heres how I want it to look:** `<p><a href="http://www.example.com">example</a></p>`

So I would actually be trying to get rid of the (/) my bad...

**HERES HOW IM USING IT:**

I am using a Rich Text Editor to write html, then sending it through a form with post method, but it keeps putting in double quotes...  I notice when I edit the source of the RTE and take out all quotes, the link works...  But I cant make my users go into the source and do that everytime, so I need a solution that does it automatically...

Comment: I know about str_replace(), but does it have the capabilities to select all quotes (") ONLY from within <a href> and </a>??

Comment: can you give a whole example input and a wanted output?

Comment: I gave an example above...  I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok.. so you could try `$result = stripslashes($string)` or do it with a regular expression like

`$result = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?=")/', '', $string )`

or

`$result = preg_replace( '/\\\\"/', '"', $string )` but better in this case would be `$result = str_replace( '\\"', '"', $string )`

edit: this works fine for me

```
$input = '<p><a href=\"http://www.example.com\">example</a></p>';

echo htmlspecialchars($input) . '<br/>';

$output = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?=")/', '', $input );

echo htmlspecialchars($output) . '<br/>';
```

Comment: oh.. my bad, I missed a backslash in my regex, updated, please try again

Comment: I dont know why but its still not even replacing the string...  Maybe its something with the echo statement... Did you review my revisions to the post above?

Comment: yo, saw it... just added two alternatives to my examples

Comment: didnt work either, but i noticed that when I simply input the following:
"
it changes " to \"

Comment: Hey, I need one more thing...  Now, whenever I put a word with an apostrophe, such as Perk's, it turns Perk's into Perk\'s ...  Any suggestions?

Comment: replace the regex to `\\\\(?="|\')`

Comment: no, that broke it, but I may have put the code in wrong, whats the whole solution?

Comment: isn't wrong, workx fine
`$output = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $input );`

Comment: Hey, got one more thing... Now it is messing up the url for linked images...  Any Suggestions?

Comment: For example, if I have a <a href="www.example.com"><img src="www.example.com/image"></img></a> it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

There were a few problems with my earlier answer, but this should work.

```
$string='<a href="gf">ahdasd"asjda</a>';
function replacequotes($matches){
return $matches[1].str_replace('"','',$matches[2]).$matches[3];
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/(<a href=)(.+?)(<\/a>)/','replacequotes',$string);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.org/nXr7XTpx

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just replace all instances of double quotes regardless of their location, then str_replace can do this as well;

```
str_replace("\"", "", $string);
```

(the backslash is used to read the quotation mark as a non-literal character)

Of course the disadvantage of this method is that it's indiscriminate, but I thought I'd post this as there are times when you want to use regular expressions such as preg_match, and other times when you just want to replace all instances of a substring within in a string.

Comment: If you're looking to remove characters from within certain parts of a string, then preg_match is the way to go. Otherwise you'd have to strip your tags before the search and then re-add them to the string, which makes things messy.

Comment: The problem now is, I cant even get my string to change based on str_replace!  I tried the above, no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Magic quotes is turned on. This is the only thing I can think of that's adding those slashes.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php